# Struts2 Property tag default escape property

Tags: java, struts2, escaping, html-escape-characters

Is there any way that in struts2 we can set the default escapeXML property to false for all property tags?

I searched through this online, seems like I could only find one person saying that this is not possible.  Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the source of the component and property tags hard-code the default value to `true`.

(I think you mean the `escapeHtml` attribute, since `escapeXml` defaults to `false`.)

I can't think of a convenient way to do it other than creating custom tags that set it to true; if you use only a subset of the tag attributes, this wouldn't be *too* onerous.

Comment: @AbSoLution8: Yeah, search the source code of the tag on Jarvana.com or a similar site, change default value and compile it. Keep in mind that it exist, and is turned on by default, for security reasons. You should be aware of which fields could be vulnerable to injection attacks by activating them yourself... otherwise, the whole application may turn into a big hole